# DropBox and Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nautilus, dropbox

I am trying to install DROPBOX in Ubuntu 17.10 using

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

All goes well until I reach

> (dropbox:2190): LIBDBUSMENU-GLBI-WARNING **: About to Show called on
>   an item without submenus.  We are ignot. Initializing nautilus-dropbox
>   1. 6. 0

Is there a specific installation package for Ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a specific package available in the official repositories as always.

Use the Ubuntu Software or, in terminal, `sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox`.